# How intent activity without calling the startactivity in android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

im developing a quiz, wherein in java class i want to intent another class(question) after i clicked the next button without using the startactivity, or is it possible to call another activity using another method to pass another activity? please help me guys..thank you so much! i hope my question is clear..i really appreciate ur help!

***Question1.java***

```
public class Question1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
int Scorecount = 0;
//private RadioGroup rgp;
private RadioButton rb1;
private RadioButton rb2;
private RadioButton rb3;
private Button b1;
//private TextView t1;
int currentQuestion = 0;
Toast t;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.startquiz);

Scorecount = getIntent().getIntExtra("score",0);
rb1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.option1);
rb2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.option2);
rb3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.option3);
b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.selected);
b1.setOnClickListener(this);
//rgp=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.QueGroup1);


//t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtdisplayanswer);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {


    if(v == b1)

    {

        if(rb1.isChecked() || rb2.isChecked() || rb3.isChecked())
        {
            if(rb1.isChecked())
            {
                Scorecount++;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your answer is correct!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                /*LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) t.getView();
                layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.toastgreen);
            //t1.setText("Your answer is correct!"  +rb1.getText());*/

            }
        /*
        if(rb2.isChecked() == true)
            //t1.setText("Your wrong, the correct answer is: "+rb1.getText());
        if(rb3.isChecked() == true)
            //t1.setText("Your wrong, the correct answer is: "+rb1.getText());*/

    else {
        // do nothing

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your answer is wrong! The correct answers is:    " + rb1.getText(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        /*LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) t.getView();
        layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.toastred);*/

    }
            //Intent i = new Intent(this,Question2.class);
            Intent i= getIntent();
            i.putExtra("score", Scorecount);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();


        }

    }

}
```

Comment: As I understand you want every single question to be a single activity which I think it's not the best implementation. I would consider using ViewPager and populate the questions from database or some kind of arrays.

Comment: Why don't you just replace the text of the question and possible answers in the **same** activity. You don't need to create another activity for that.

Comment: Absolutrely agree with what the former commenters said. You need to find a more generic solution. For example store the question text and the number of the correct answer (if these are only multiple choice single answer questions) in the database. Now query the db in the activity (using a Loader) based on the id of the current question.

Answer (score 0):

try using fragment instead of activity, and you dont have to use start activity for each of new fragment.To change the screen you have to just do a transaction of removing old fragment and adding the new one.And this mechanism is also more memory efficient than using multiple activity to show each different question.